# MQTT 1884 connection failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mqtt, paho

I am using mqtt for a messaging system on my site. Well on my local machine everything works fine but on my site (production) I am getting an error:

> vendor.bbaf8c4….bundle.js:1 WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:1884/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I am using Ubuntu within my Webserver and I gave the port 1884 free.

What this error meaning?

I am using Angular4 and I add the connection within AfterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{

        this.messageservice.createMqttConnection(this.userId);
    }, 200)

}
```

The connection with Paho on my client site looks like:

```
  this._client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost", 1884, id.toString());
```

Let assume my domains is mydomain.com should I replace it with localhost?

Comment: localhost is the address for the machine the code is running on, I assume this needs changing to point to your production environment

Comment: ok lets assume my domain name is mydomain.com, should I replace it with localhost?  this._client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost", 1884, id.toString());

Comment: The other way round, you should replace `localhost` with `mydomain.com`

Comment: Ok thanks works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thrashed out in the comments:

The hostname in your app needs to point to your domain e.g. `mydomain.com` not `localhost`

`localhost` will always point to the machine the code is running on so is very unlikely to be what you want for a production deployment of an application.